# iText to convert HTML to PDF on Android, CSS issue

Tags: java, android, html, pdf, itext

I'm trying to convert my HTML with external CSS files to PDF by using iText library

it works well on normal Java project **but** when i tried to use same source code in android it doesn't work because there's no java.awt.* in android sdk.

I tried use iTextG but CSS also doesn't work. I still get just text from HTML in my PDF file

Is there any way to do this?

There's my code :

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/PDFTest/test.pdf"));
document.open();
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new FileInputStream("/sdcard/PDFTest/index.html"));
document.close();
```

Comment: are you using itexg?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the solution i can simply change 
`XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new FileInputStream("html file"));`

to

`XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new FileInputStream("html file"), new FileInputStream("css file"));`

Comment: i have the same issue, i tried this but i only get the text the css is not being  used